# Setter function not updating property values

Tags: javascript

```js
var book = {};
Object.defineProperties(book, {
  _year: {
    value: 2004
  },
  edition: {
    value: 1
  },
  year: {
    get: function() {
      return this._year;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      if (newValue > 2004) {
        this._year = newValue;
        this.edition += newValue - 2004;
      }
    }
  }
});
book.year = 2006;
alert(book.year); // 2004
alert(book.edition); // 1
```

Why do the `alert`s show the old property values, even though the setter should update the properties?

Comment: What, exactly, is expected ??/

Comment: Would be great if you could also tell us what exactly the issue is your are talking about.

Comment: when I am assigning 2006 to book.year, then as per the setter, the value of _year should change but it still returns 2004 which is the original value.

Comment: There, fixed it for you. Is it so hard to describe what happens and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Thanks Felix for fixing it. This is my first question on the forum and I guess it will improve with time.

Comment: Fair enough :) I recommend to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . FWIW, you got an upvote for me. It's a "good" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) writable as the default value of writable is `false`

```js
var book = {};
Object.defineProperties(book, {
  _year: {
    value: 2004,
    writable: true
  },
  edition: {
    value: 1,
    writable: true
  },
  year: {
    get: function() {
      return this._year;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      if (newValue > 2004) {
        this._year = newValue;
        this.edition += newValue - 2004;
      }
    }
  }
});
book.year = 2006;
alert(book.year);
alert(book.edition);
```

Comment: You should add why this is necessary (because they are not writable by default).

Comment: Thanks Arun for the answer but that makes me a bit more confused. As far as I know, by default, the properties defined are writable and configurable. Is this not the case in some scenarios?

Comment: @Abeer yes.... by default properties are writable... but when you use `definePropety` to define a properties behavior then the default nature of the defined property is non writable